# Bicep/ARM XML parameter as string not parsed correctly

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

In my Bicep file, I have a parameter:

```
@secure()
param securityToken string
```

This parameter is an XML value provided as a string from an environment variable, not read from a file. I have trouble correctly setting this parameter from my YML pipeline. I have this piece of code:

```
az deployment sub create --template-file main.bicep --parameters securityToken='<xml>'
```

Unfortunately, this returns an error:

```
< was unexpected at this time.
```

Ok, so I somehow have to escape this parameter? I also tried:

```
az deployment sub create --template-file main.bicep --parameters securityToken='&lt;xml&gt;'
```

But this gives the following error:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

**So my questions is:**

How can I provide an XML string parameter to my Bicep / ARM deployment?

Thanks!

Comment: Please note for the future that the [tag:arm] tag is for the ARM (Advanced RISC Machine) CPU architecture.  The tag you want here is [tag:azure-resource-manager].

Answer (score 0):

Deployments to subscriptions need the `--location <location>` parameter, which is missing in the examples above.

When I run the following on Windows, Git Bash, the deployment succeeds.

```
az deployment sub create --location eastus --template-file main.bicep --parameters securityToken='<xml>'
```

Result
[image]

main.bicep

```
targetScope = 'subscription'

@secure()
param securityToken string

output exposedSecret string = securityToken
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I left out all the other parameters to make things clearer in my question; I did have the --location at the end. The <xml> tag is really the problem.

I'm really surprised this works out of the box for you. For me it really doesn't. I read somewhere in the Microsoft docs you have to escape the < and > by putting it between ". This made it work:  "<"xml">"

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem. Apparently, the < and > needs to be escaped, and I finally found out how: putting it between ". So, the value "<"xml">" did the trick. Now my working code is this:

```
$token = '<xml></xml>'
$token = $token .replace('<', '"<"') // = "<"xml>"<"/xml>
$token = $token .replace('>', '">"') // = "<"xml">""<"/xml">"
$token = $token .replace('""', '" "') // The double "" only escapes the " itself. Therefore, add an extra space: "<"xml">" "<"/xml">"
```